# How to use custom version of List: `data List a = Nil | Cons a (List a)`?

Tags: list, haskell, types, syntax, custom-data-type

This question is based on an example from the chapter *"Declaring Types and Classes"* of the book *"Programming in Haskell"* by Graham Hutton, *second edition*.

The data declaration is:
`data List a = Nil | Cons a (List a)`

The example function that uses this declaration is:

```
len :: List a -> Int
len Nil = 0
len (Cons _ xs) = 1 + len xs
```

But no matter what I've tried, I can't seem to use the function `len`:

- `len Cons 1 Cons 2 Cons 3`
- `len 1`
- `len Cons`
- `len (1)`
- `len [1,2]`
- `len Cons [1]`
- `len (1,2)`
- `len Cons (1,2)`
- `len Cons 1 2`
- `len (Cons (1,2))`
- `len (Cons 1 2)`

Did I miss out any permutation of `len` and `Cons`?  Or is the example simply unworkable?

Comment: It might be simpler to start out with trying to implement an expression of type `foo :: List Int` first. Lists are recursive datatypes, so it can be a little tricky at first to see how to "finish off" the recursion. But there is a way to construct a list that does not involve using another list.

Comment: @AsadSaeeduddin: Thanks, I finally got it to work with `len (Cons 2 (Cons 2 Nil))`.  It would seem that Haskell self declared functions usually result in rather lengthy terms.

Comment: You could declare an infix constructor. It has to be something starting with `:`. E.g. `:.`. With the appropriate fixity declaration you could have `len $ 1 :. 2 :. 3 :. Nil`.

Answer (score 3):

The parameters you pass to the `len` are not `List`s. The end of a list has `Nil`, so lists are of the form `Nil`, `Cons … Nil`, `Cons … (Cons … Nil)`, `Cons … (Cons … (Cons … Nil))`, etc. So eventually for each list, the end of the list is marked with `Nil`. `Nil` is the equivalent to `[]` for Haskell's `[a]` type.

Furthermore you can not pass `len Cons 1 Nil` for example, since then it will be interpreted as `((len Cons) 1) Nil`. The parameter should be a list. By using parenthesis, you can write this as `len (Cons 1 Nil)`.

For the given sample data, you thus can rewrite this to:

- <s>`len Cons 1 Cons 2 Cons 3`</s> → `len (Cons 1 (Cons 2 (Cons 3 Nil)))`
- <s>`len 1`</s> → `len (Cons 1 Nil)`
- <s>`len Cons`</s> → `len Nil`
- <s>`len (1)`</s> → `len (Cons 1 Nil)`
- <s>`len [1,2]`</s> → `len (Cons 1 (Cons 2 Nil))`
- <s>`len Cons [1]`</s> → `len (Cons 1 Nil)`
- <s>`len (1,2)`</s> → `len (Cons 1 (Cons 2 Nil))`
- <s>`len Cons (1,2)`</s> → `len (Cons 1 (Cons 2 Nil))`
- <s>`len Cons 1 2`</s> → `len (Cons 1 (Cons 2 Nil))`
- <s>`len (Cons (1,2))`</s> → `len (Cons 1 (Cons 2 Nil))`
- <s>`len (Cons 1 2)`</s> → `len (Cons 1 (Cons 2 Nil))`

You can also make use of the [**`OverloadedLists`** [haskell-doc]](https://downloads.haskell.org/%7Eghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#extension-OverloadedLists) extension to use list syntax instead. In that case, you need to implement the [**`IsList`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/GHC-Exts.html#t:IsList) type class:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}

import GHC.Exts(IsList(..))

data List a = Nil | Cons a (List a)

instance IsList (List a) where
    type Item (List a) = a
    toList Nil = []
    toList (Cons x xs) = x : toList xs
    fromList [] = Nil
    fromList (x:xs) = Cons x (fromList xs)
```

If you then enable the `OverloadedLists` extension, you can write these as list literals:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedLists #-}

-- …

main = print (len [1,2])
```

Answer (score 0):

You use a function exactly as it is defined:

```
len  Nil         = 0
len (Cons _x xs) = 1 + len xs
```

then,

```
list1 = Nil           -- matches the first pattern
list2 = Cons 2 list1  -- matches the second pattern
list3 = Cons 3 list2  -- matches the second pattern
list4 = Cons 4 list3  -- matches the second pattern
```

and so on and so forth.

Writing out such example data by hand we need to use parentheses to correctly group the sub-terms to recreate the valid term, as e.g.

```
list5 = Cons 5 list4
      = Cons 5 (Cons 4 list3)
      = Cons 5 (Cons 4 (Cons 3 list2))
      = ...
      = Cons 5 (Cons 4 (Cons 3 (Cons 2 Nil)))
```

All this without even having looked at the data type definition.

Of course anything can be used in place of `1`, `2`, etc., as long as they are all of *the same type*, e.g. the following is also a valid term:

```
list54 = Cons list5 (Cons list4 Nil)
```

Why? Because of the data type definition,

```
data List a = Nil           --  `Nil` constructs (is) a valid `List a` type term,
            |               -- OR,
              Cons          --  `Cons x xs` constructs (is) a valid `List a` type term,  IF 
                   a        --       `x` is a valid term of type `a`                  ,  AND
                  (List a)  --       `xs` is a valid term of type `List a`
```

`Nil` constructs (is) a valid `List a` type term, while `Cons x xs` constructs (is) a valid `List a` type term, *if* `x` is a valid term of type `a` *and* `xs` is a valid term of type `List a`, ***where `a` is one and the same***.

So e.g. `Cons 1 (Cons list2 Nil)` is not a valid term according to the `List a` data type definition, even though the function `len` could seemingly handle it as well.