# I couldn't figure out how to use sInsert function. Can you help me?

Tags: haskell

I couldn't figure out how to use `sInsert` function. Can you help me?

```
sInsert :: Ord a => a -> Tree a -> Tree a
sInsert x Nil = Node x Nil Nil
sInsert x (Node a t1 t2) = if x <= a
                        then Node a (sInsert x t1) t2
                        else Node a t1 (sInsert x t2)
```

`sInsert (???)`

Comment: [related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63109900/849891).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could construct a tree starting from `Nil` and then inserting data in it. For instance, here's a small list of expressions you can try to evaluate in GHCi:

```
sInsert "c" Nil
sInsert "a" (sInsert "c" Nil)
sInsert "b" (sInsert "a" (sInsert "c" Nil))
...
```

Comment: I have got error    |
51 |     print(sInsert "c" Nil)
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Comment: @ColibV Did you declare your tree type using something like `deriving Show`? Otherwise, you can't print the result.

Comment: It is my tree type declaration : data Tree a = Node a (Tree a) (Tree a) | Nil
                deriving Eq

Comment: I have edited my type declaration and your example has begun to work. Thank you.